# How to get immediately following siblings up to next unmatched selector

Tags: jquery, xpath, jquery-selectors, dom-traversal

I have the following table

```
<table id="table">
<tr><td>Item</td></tr>
<tr class="hide"><td>Hidden Item</td></tr>
<tr class="hide"><td>Hidden Item</td></tr>
<tr class="hide"><td>Hidden Item</td></tr>
<tr><td>Item</td></tr>
<tr class="hide"><td>Hidden Item</td></tr>
<tr class="hide"><td>Hidden Item</td></tr>
<tr><td>Item</td></tr>
<tr class="hide"><td>Hidden Item</td></tr>
<tr class="hide"><td>Hidden Item</td></tr>
<tr class="hide"><td>Hidden Item</td></tr>
<tr class="hide"><td>Hidden Item</td></tr>
<tr><td>Item</td></tr>
</table>
```

on clicking on a visible row, i want to show all the immediately following hidden rows up to the next visible row. The number of hidden rows is not fixed. How can I select immediately following rows up to a specific element?

Comment: group those hidden items into a chunk using class and do jQuery's `fadeIn()` when clicked on the parent visible element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
//Add a class to your visible rows if possible to replace the next selector
$('tr:visible').click(function() {
    $('.hide').hide();
    $(this).nextUntil(':visible').fadeIn();
});​
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/NNWYs/2/)

[`.nextUntil()` Reference](http://api.jquery.com/nextUntil/)

---

Adding a `show` class to the visible rows, you can add a simple toggle effect to it:

```
$('.show').click(function() {
    $(this).nextUntil('.show').not('.show').fadeToggle();
});
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/NNWYs/4/)

---

A slightly more elaborated version which toggles the clicked rows' section and hides the rows which were previously open:

```
$('.show').click(function() {
    $('.hide').not(
        $(this).nextUntil('.show').not('.show').fadeToggle()
    ).hide();
});
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/NNWYs/3/)

Comment: What is the need for `$(this).next()`?

Comment: `$(this).next()` is to start selecting rows after the clicked one - it selects the first hidden row onwards. In case you're just displaying these and not toggling them, it doesn't make much difference.

Comment: But yes, by calling `andSelf` on it makes the `.next()` just redundant, editing it out.

Comment: Thanks. I provided a simplified table above. The actual table has a class for the visible rows. I'll use that.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [.nextUntil()](http://api.jquery.com/nextUntil/) - replacing $('tr:first') with your element -

```
$('tr:first').nextUntil('tr:not(.hide)').show()
// from first tr until next one that doesn't have class=hide
```

Though I would probably use toggle() to hide/show the following elements - I'm not sure what your goal is though so you can do what you want afterwards

```
$('.hide').hide();
$('tr:not(.hide)').click(function(){   
    $(this).nextUntil('tr:not(.hide)').toggle();    
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nqTJc/

​

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you are looking for: [jQuery .nextUntil()](http://api.jquery.com/nextUntil/)

Answer (score 1):

use nextUntil

```
$('tr').click(function(){

 $(this).nextUntil(':not("tr.hide")').show();

});​​
```

find jsfiddle
  http://jsfiddle.net/K5QcA/

for reference
 http://api.jquery.com/nextUntil/